# Show the properties of this relation! Is my solution correct?

Tags: calculus, relations

`enter preformatted text here`Let $X = \mathbb{N}^+$ and define $\preccurlyeq$ relation on $X$ set:

$$x \preccurlyeq y \Leftrightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{N} : y = kx$$

a.) Show that $\preccurlyeq$ is an (partial) order.

b.) Let $A=\{6, 10\}$. Give the smallest and minimum element/elements, if those exists.

c.) Show the infimum of $A$.

a.) $X=\mathbb{N}^+$ 
$$ x \preccurlyeq\ y \Leftrightarrow x\mid y $$
A relation is an partial order if it's  reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive.

- reflexive:  $$x \mid x \quad x \leq x: \quad \exists k \in \mathbb{N} \quad x=k*x \quad k=1$$
- antisymmetric: $$x \leq y: \quad \exists k_1 \in \mathbb{N}: \quad y=k_1*x$$
  $$y \leq x: \quad \exists k_2 \in \mathbb{N}: \quad x=k_2*y$$
  $$y=k_1k_2*y, \quad where \quad k_1k_2=1 \quad and \quad k_1=k_2=1 \Rightarrow  x=y$$
- transitive: $$ x \leq y: \quad \exists k_1 \in \mathbb{N}: \quad y=k_1*x$$
  $$ y \leq z: \quad \exists k_2 \in \mathbb{N}: \quad z=k_2*y$$
  $$z=|k_1k_2|*x, \quad where \quad |k_1k_2| \in \mathbb{N} \quad so \quad x \leq z$$

b.) $A=\{6, 10\}$

minimum element:

$$6 \leq 6 \quad \checkmark; \quad 6 \leq 10 \quad  this \quad is \quad a \quad contradiction, \quad because \quad \nexists k \in \mathbb{N}: \quad 6*k = 10$$
$$10 \leq 6 \quad this \quad is \quad a \quad contradiction, \quad because  \quad \nexists k \in \mathbb{N}: \quad 10*k = 6; \quad 10 \leq 10 \quad \checkmark$$

$\Rightarrow \nexists \quad minimum \quad element$

smallest element:

$$\nexists x: x \leq 6 \Leftarrow 10 \nleq 6, \quad because \quad \nexists k \in \mathbb{N}: 6=k*10 $$
$$\nexists x: x \leq 10 \Leftarrow 6 \nleq 10, \quad because \quad \nexists k \in \mathbb{N}: 10=k*6 $$

c.) infimum of $A$

$infA=gcd\left(6,10\right)$

$ 2 \leq 6;10 \quad 1 \leq 6;10$

Lower bounds: $1, 2$

$divisors \quad of \quad 6: 1, 2, 3 \qquad because \quad 1;2;3*k=6$
$divisors \quad of \quad 10: 1, 2, 5 \quad because \quad 1;2;5*k=10$

$\Rightarrow the \quad common \quad divisors \quad of \quad 6 \quad  and \quad 10: 1, 2$

So only $1$ and $2$ could be the lower bounds of $A$ because $\nexists k_1 \in \mathbb{N}: 3*k_1=10$ and $\nexists k_2 \in \mathbb{N}: 5*k_2=6$

According to the definition of infimum:

$$1 \leq 2 \Rightarrow infA=2$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: You didn't show, in proving antisymmetric for part a), that from $k_1k_2=1$ it follows that $k_1=k_2=1.$ This is true but needs a proof.

Comment: I would like to see a clear answer in b). Write clearly what is your conclusion.

Comment: In which part? I rewrote my answer where I showed that no minimum unit exists.

Comment: What's the difference between minimum and smallest?

Answer (score 0):

For a)

1. There's a typo in proving antisymmetry. It should be $x=k_1\cdot y$ instead of $x=k_2\cdot x$.
2. Maybe a word about how you get to $k_1=k_2=1$ from $k_1k_2=1$ would be nice
3. In proving transitivity, there's no real need for absolute values.

---

For b) I don't really know what "smallest" means, and I don't know what you mean by "unit" (do you mean "element") but your proof there is no minimum element of $A$ is correct.

---

For c)

You only proved that $2$ is a lower bound for $A$. You didn't prove that $1$ and $2$ are the *only* lower bounds for $A$, so you didn't yet prove that $2$ is the infimum (i.e., the largest lower bound).

Comment: @nah By proving that $1$ and $2$ are the only two lower bounds for $A$.

Comment: I think I managed to prove it. And I showed why $k_1=k_2=1$

Comment: @nah You can't say "$k_1=k_2$ because $x=y$", because $x=y$ is what you **want to prove**.

Comment: I don't know how to prove that. It looks trivial that $k_1=k_2=1$ because both $k_1$ and $k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$. If $k_1; k_2 \neq 1$ than $\frac{1}{k_2}  \quad or  \quad \frac{1}{k_1} \notin \mathbb{N}$.